# In Angular7, How can i get an object response from my .subscribe http response from api

Tags: spring-boot, angular7

I wish i have my list updated when i add a new object 'puits'.
So i need to get my object "pts" as a 'puits'  that i just added, as a response from the subscribe, or maybe another method?
I think i can use httpOptions or something, to get my object puits,
and use a fonction get, with the "location" of the headers ?

```
//my code in my component :  
puits: Puits[] = [];

  pts: Puits = {
    nom: 'OP100',
    idSite: 1,
    idtypepuits: 1,
  };

ngOnInit() {
    this.getPuits();
  }

add(nom: string): void {
    nom = nom.trim();
    if (!nom) { return; }
    this.puitsService.addPuits({ nom } as Puits)
     .subscribe( pts  => {this.puits.push(pts);
      });
  }    


//my code in my service :     
addPuits (puits: Puits): Observable<Puits> {
  return this.http.post<Puits>(this.puitsUrl, puits, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((newPuits: Puits) => this.log(`Puits ajouté au nom=${newPuits.nom}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Puits>('addPuits'))
  );
}

//my server response when i add a puits :    
Location →http://localhost:9090/Base_Puits/Puits/272    
Content-Length →0    
Date →Thu, 07 Feb 2019 09:54:58 GMT
```

Comment: Your backend returns no data (content-length -> 0). You need to either `1)` return the data on save or `2)` call that endpoint that comes in `location` and then update your list

Comment: 2) yes, it's what i trying to do. but i don't know, how to call the `location` in the component/in the subscribe. If you can help me on this point, i will really appreciate.

Comment: but what's the problem? don't you know how to access the header? Or where's the issue?

Comment: yes i don't know how to acces the header.location, in my component, and applied a get on it